# Strapi: where global models comes from?

Tags: strapi

For example, I've created content type "Item" via admin panel. In `/api/item/services/Item.js` I see code like

```
 fetchAll: (params) => {
const convertedParams = strapi.utils.models.convertParams('item', params);

return Item
  .find()
  .where(convertedParams.where)
  .sort(convertedParams.sort)
  .skip(convertedParams.start)
  .limit(convertedParams.limit)
  .populate(_.keys(_.groupBy(_.reject(strapi.models.item.associations, {autoPopulate: false}), 'alias')).join(' '));
},
```

but `Item` is not imported, so it is global.

1. I'd like to know in what moment this global `Item` is created?
2. What is the difference between global `Item` and `strapi.models.item`?
3. I'm making GraphQL support via middleware, so I'll put model in context object. What's the best way to use `item` model: like service, `strapi.models.item` or `Item`?

Thank you.

PS: if one of the authors of Strapi will read this, could you please tell why are you using global objects so heavily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Global models are created on `strapi-mongoose` or `strapi-bookshelf` (depending of the database you use) It's in this node module we create instances of your models.
2. There is no difference between them `Item` === `strapi.models.item`
3. I think your middleware will have a dynamic logic so I recommend you to use `strapi.models` and `strapi.plugins[plugin].models`.

You are able to custom then global name of your models to be more easy to use https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#models
So the global name can change but not the path in the `strapi` object.